Why was this thread deleted, and is there anything to do about it?
Yesterday, I answered a very basic question about the interpretation of percentages, and got a couple of upvotes from my answer. I don't have the original link to the question, but if it can help retrieving it, the question was about the correctness of extrapolating the percentage of title fraud cases settled out of court from the percentage of lawsuits settled out of court (which is incorrect no matter if the question was about lawsuits or about something else, and my answer was explaining that to the OP).
It looks like the question completely vanished from the website (it was not closed, it simply disappeared from the website – so apparently the problem seems to be more than just the question being possibly not focused enough, off-topic, etc.).
I re-read the thread about deleted questions, and the only possible explanations I see is that the OP account has been destroyed, or that the question has been directly deleted by a moderator. I invested some time in answering the question (not a lot, but still) and it's a bit disappointing to lose some reputation over its deletion. Under which conditions can deleted questions like that can be restored?
If there's nothing to do about it, I guess the lesson here is to be more careful about the questions we choose to answer.
Edit: I found the link to the question from my "deleted answers" page, here it is for those who have access to it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/650708/am-i-interpreting-title-fraud-statistics-correctly/650711 It looks like that the OP account has been deleted/destroyed.

The q. was posted by a sock-puppet of a prolific troll, & quickly flagged by users familiar with his modus operandi from other sites on S.E. I'm not sure though that the question (& your answer) needed to be deleted as well as the troll's account. One option is just to undelete the question & hope he doesn't come back; the other is to re-ask it, or an equivalent question, & re-post your answer to that.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. If restoring the question is possibly an incentive for this person to come back, then it may be wise not to restore it and I don't have a problem with that. Anyway, I'll be more careful when answering questions from new accounts, in particular when questions seem particularly simple.

I'll try & find out what the risks are & how best to handle them (we don't get many trolls here). It's be a shame if simple questions were to go unanswered for fear they're asked by someone who just wants to muck about with us.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thanks. What I meant is that now, I'll wait a bit before answering such questions (I didn't mean that I will never answer simple questions again). In any case, thanks to the team of moderators for your work.

My advice, if you thought you had a good answer, would be to try to formulate a canonical version of the question (one that will be the most use to later readers) and then post a good canonical answer. It is okay to answer your own questions; I'd point to some of Ben O'Neill's self-answered questions as excellent examples of the genre. I've done that a few times in response to a question being removed and some of the answers ended up being pretty popular.
